# setting text automatically in autocompletextview based on selection of another autocompletetextview

Tags: android, sqlite

I have written a program to set text automatically in two autocompletetextview based on selection of single autocompletetextview but getting an error.

06-27 16:17:42.369: E/CursorWindow(7974): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 3 columns.

```
cursor = listHelper.getVehicleData();
                int[] vehicleNoTo = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }; 
                String[] vehicleNoFrom = new String[] { 
                DbListHelper.REGISTRATION_NO };
                SimpleCursorAdapter driverAdapter = new 
                SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, 
                        vehicleNoFrom, vehicleNoTo);

                 driverAdapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new 
                 CursorToStringConverter() 
                 { 
                     public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cur) 
                         { 
                         int index =  
                         cur.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.REGISTRATION_NO); 
                         return cur.getString(index); 
                          } 
                     });

                 editVehicleNo1.setAdapter(driverAdapter);
                 editVehicleNo1.setThreshold(1);
                 driverAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The above code works perfectly for one autocompletetextview - showing registration nos of vehicle,when I start typing.

But what I want is , when I select on any vehicle nos , driver name(autocomplete) and driver code(autocomplete) should get set.

So I have written for the above logic , but gets an error here:

```
editVehicleNo1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int 
                    before, int count) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                            int count,
                            int after) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        driverName1 =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                                     (DbListHelper.DRIVER_NAME));
                        driverCode1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                                      (DbListHelper.DRIVER_CODE));
                        editDriverName.setText(driverName1);
                        editDriverCode.setText(driverCode1);

                    }
                });
```

SqliteHelper.java for insertion and selection of vehicle database

```
public long insertVehicleData(String vehicle_code,String 
    registration_no,String driver_code,String driver_name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DbListHelper.VEHICLE_CODE, vehicle_code);
    values.put(DbListHelper.REGISTRATION_NO, registration_no);
    values.put(DbListHelper.DRIVER_CODE, driver_code);
    values.put(DbListHelper.DRIVER_NAME, driver_name);
    long id = db.insert(DbListHelper.TABLE_NAME_VEHICLE, null, values);
    return id;
}

public Cursor getVehicleData(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = { 
    DbListHelper.UID,DbListHelper.VEHICLE_CODE,DbListHelper.REGISTRATION_NO
            ,DbListHelper.DRIVER_CODE,DbListHelper.DRIVER_NAME};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DbListHelper.TABLE_NAME_VEHICLE, columns, null, 
                    null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int index0 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.UID);
        String cid0 = cursor.getString(index0);
        int index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.VEHICLE_CODE);
        String cid1 = cursor.getString(index1);
        int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.REGISTRATION_NO);
        String cid2 = cursor.getString(index2);
        int index3 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.DRIVER_CODE);
        String cid3 = cursor.getString(index3);
        int index4 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.DRIVER_NAME);
        String cid4 = cursor.getString(index4);

        buffer.append(cid0 + " " + cid1 + " " + cid2 + " " + cid3 + " " + 
        cid4 +  "\n");
    }
    return cursor;

}
```

Comment: what is editDriverName & editDriverCode? and what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink editDriverName and editDriverCode are autocompletetextview , and editVehicleNo1 is also autocompletetextview , when i start typing in editvehicleno1 a dropdown comes which has a list of vehicle nos , so when i select any of the vehicle no , i want that the driver name and driver code should be automatically filled up

Comment: i dont get it: why you setup them but later they can be changed? also what is `StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();` used for???

Answer (score 0):

Replace the while loop of `getVechileData()` in `SqliteHelper.java`

```
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int index0 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.UID);
        String cid0 = cursor.getString(index0);
       //Your code.............
    }
```

with

```
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
              int index0 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.UID);
              String cid0 = cursor.getString(index0);
              //Your code......
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
```

`cursor.moveToFirst()` must called after the query it will return if there are any records in the database otherwise it returns false.

In the `onTextChanged()` you cannot get the values from the cursor directly first call `cursor.moveToFirst()` and then get then values.

```
 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      if (cursor.moveToFirst(
             driverName1 =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex (DbListHelper.DRIVER_NAME));
          }
     }
```

Comment: @narahari_arjun Updated my answer have a look

Comment: `while (cursor.moveToNext())` is perfectly **OK**, dont make simple things complex

Comment: @Kartheek sir , had to manipulate a little but the if(cursor.movetofirst()) on aftertextchanged worked , thanx alot

Comment: @pskink If you call 'while (cursor.moveToNext()) ' before reading the cursor then it will skip the first record.It the above question he can never the read the first record he will always skipping it. before downvoting Please make sure you are correct.

Comment: now see what is the position of the Cursor after it is returned by: `Cursor cursor = db.query`, yes: position is -1, `moveToNext` just moves to the first position, and yes i am correct, also the `while (c.moveToNext())` pattern is commonly used in android source code so i think is preferred by google devs, also see SQLiteDatabase.query docs: **"Returns
A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry. Note that Cursors are not synchronized, see the documentation for more details."**

Comment: @Kartheek here you can see usage of `moveToNext` in AOSP: http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/search?q=&defs=&refs=moveToNext&path=&hist=&project=abi&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=ndk&project=packages&project=pdk&project=prebuilts&project=sdk&project=system&project=tools